# How do I specifiy specific element with Capybara?

Tags: capybara

I'm testing if the Google Maps api works and loads, so upon loading I would like to confirm specific elements inside the map to make sure it loaded.

My code so far:

```
# ... prob put a sleep 1 here maybe to account for possible delay in map load
expect(page).to have_css ('#map')

section = find('#map')
expect(section).to have_css('.gm-control-active')
```

However, there are 3 .gm-control-active elements inside the Google Map:

```
1) aria-label="Zoom in" title="Zoom in"
2) aria-label="Zoom out" title="Zoom out"
3) aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" title= "Toggle fullscreen view"
```

What's the syntax to specify one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any css, which includes being able to use attribute selectors. Therefore you could do something like

```
expect(section).to have_css('.gm-control-active[title=“Zoom in”]')
```

Or whatever other attributes you want to match against

Comment: actually gives me error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110)
from #0 0x5583985bc4e3 <unknown>
`

Comment: @daveasdf What code exactly did you use? If you just copy/pasted what I put in the answer you'll likely have to change the "s since stackoverflow "helpfully" changes them to typographer quotes

Comment: Wow.  I appreciate that, ty. I will google typographer quotes tomorrow